# Count vowels in each of the strings using two dimensional array

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, char, nested-loops, c-strings

I need to write a program where the user enters the number of strings and the program counts the number of vowels in each string and prints the total number of vowels.
The following code works *without* two dimensional array

```
int countVoweles(char inputArray[])
{
    int total = 0;
    char vowels[] = "aAeEiIoOuU";
    for (int i = 0; inputArray[i]; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; vowels[j]; j++)
        {
            if (inputArray[i] == vowels[j])
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

However, the following code does not work *with* two dimensional array. It prints vowels only from the first string.

How can I print vowels from all strings entered?

```
char name[3][10];
    int total = 0;
    char vowels[] = "aAeEiIoOuU";
    printf("Enter your string :");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        gets(name[i]);
    }
    printf("The total number of vowels are :\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; name[i][j]; j++)
        {
            if (name[i][j] == vowels[i])
            {
                total++;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%d", total);
```

Comment: `if (name[i][j] == vowels[i])` makes no sense. `i` is not a proper index into the `vowels` array. You need a third loop with a third index, to loop through the `vowels` array.

Comment: `gets` was deprecated around 25 years ago and finally completely removed 11 years ago. Who told you to use it?

Comment: My teacher said it is okay to use it, but then he is 66 years old...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters pay attention to that the function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported by the C Standard. Instead use the standard function `fgets` as for example

```
fgets( name[i], sizeof( name[i] ), stdin );
```

As for your problem then you need one more loop to traverse the array with `vowels` for a given character in strings of the array `name`.

For example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; name[i][j]; j++)
    {
        int k = 0;
        while ( vowels[k] && name[i][j] != vowels[k] ) ++k;
        if ( vowels[k] )
        {
            total++;
        }
    }
}
```

Another approach is to use your already written function like

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    total += countVoweles( name[i] );
}
```

Instead of using a loop to traverse the array `vowels` you could use standard C function `strchr` declared in the header `<string.h>` as for example

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; name[i][j]; j++)
    {
        total += strchr( vowels, name[i][j] ) != NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for further explanation. You are very helpful. We need more humans like you in this world :)

Answer (score 1):

Your function needs to know what is the size of the 2D char array.

```
size_t countVoweles(size_t lines, size_t chars, char inputArray[lines][chars])
{
    size_t total = 0;
    const char vowels[] = "aAeEiIoOuU";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < lines; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; inputArray[i][j]; j++)
        {
            total += !!strchr(vowels, inputArray[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return total;
}

int main(void)
{

    char x[][256] = {
        "<Compilation failed>",
        "# For more information see the output window",
        "# To open the output window, click or drag the \"Output\" icon at the bottom of this window",
    };
    printf("%zu\n", countVoweles(sizeof(x)/ sizeof(x[0]), sizeof(x[0]), x));
}
```